# how to save data while reloading scene in unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to reload scene and update just one variable leaving everything else untouched. **I also want to peek data from inspector**.

I tried the following method:

```
                  SceneManager.LoadScene(scene, LoadSceneMode.Single);
```

but whole scene loses its data. Is it possible to update just one variable while reloading? 
Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to save all the game states which matters before reloading the scene like enemies positions their health,players health and weapon etc and load them then assign them to your in game variables in the start of the scene.
you can achieve  this by using [serialization](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-save-and-load-your-players-progress-in-unity--cms-20934) techniques